# double value cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java

I'm just not sure why I'm getting this error, I would appreciate it if you could help me out to find the error. here is the code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstSelectionProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner key=new Scanner(System.in);

        double spent;

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Amount That You Have Spent: ");
        spent= key.nextDouble();

        if (0.01=<spent && spent=<40)
        {
            System.out.println("you will receive 20% off");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("you won't receive anything");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Double` should be `double` and the `=` should go on the right of the inequality.

Comment: [Official java operator documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: `=<` should be `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `if (0.01=<spent && spent=<40)` try `if (0.01 <= spent && spent <= 40)`